# PNG Does The transparent pixel take up memory?

Tags: android, png, transparency, transparent

I'm making a game for Android and I'm using transparent PNG's. But does the transparent part take up large memory?

For example if I have a PNG that is `512*512` that is transparent, does that take up the same amount of `RAM` and or `ROM` as one with `256*246`??

//Simon

Comment: Could you not just create each one, and compare their sizes?

Comment: Meant more RAM than in kb on disk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size depends entirely on the pictures resolution when beeing uncompressed in memory.

If you have pixel with transparency *(an alpha-channel)*, you are most likely using `ARGB8888` as the image format. With this each pixel takes 4 bytes in memory. Which means the 512x512 pixel image takes `(512*512*4) bytes = 1 MB` and the smaller on `(256*246*4) bytes = 246 kB`.

If the pixels are transparent *(invisible)* or not doesn't matter. Only resolution and internal format are relevant.

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN Yes, memory = RAM in this case.

Answer (score 4):

When your image is loaded into the memory it will be a bitmap, no matter what the original format on the disc was, so it really depends on what [Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) you load your image with.
If you load your image as `ARGB_8888`, every color component of every pixel of the image will take up one byte, i.e. **the alpha (transparency) will take up one fourth of the total image memory** and every pixel will be 4 bytes.

- An image that is **512x512 pixels with transparency** will take
  about **1048 kB memory**.
- **Without transparency** it will be **786kB**.
- There isn't any RGB_888 colormode, the closest is **RGB_565**, which
  would be **524kB**.